# assert that a service has been injected as scoped service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, nunit-3.0

I am writing a unit test for the following extension method:

```cs
public static void AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IServiceA, ServiceA>();
}
```

Here is what I have to confirm the `ServiceA` has been injected.

```cs
[Test]
public void Should_Resolve_ServiceA() {
    // Arrange
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    // Act
    services.AddMyServices();
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var actual = serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceA>();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);        
}
```

The test above did ensure the service has been injected. However, `services.AddSingleton` and `services.AddTransient` also pass the test.

Is there a solution to get only the scoped injected services so I can ensure it has been injected the correct way?

*I am aware that for the simplified example above, I can create a stub for `IServiceCollection` and check the `ReceivedCalls` on the stub method. However, I am trying to avoid doing that because I have a lot of `AddScope` statements in my real extension method and part of the purpose of the unit test above is to ensure all dependencies of a specific service have been injected. So `GetService<T>` is the preferred way to do the testing.*

Comment: I doubt there is a way to tell using the default DI library.   You /could/ verify by creating an instance, opening your own scope, create another instance, and then if the 2 instances are the same, then it's not singleton.  Also, just create 2 instances, and if they are the same, it's not transient.

Comment: Neil answer +1. If you are using ASP.NET Core, the above code should not even work as scoped services need to be resolved in a scoped context, I. e. `using var scope = sp.CreateScope(); var actual = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IServiceA>();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once the service is added in the `ServiceCollection`, you should be able to get back the `ServiceDescriptor` to verify the service scope. Note that `ServiceCollection` is an `IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor>`. So you can check it like this:

```
// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(services.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ServiceType == typeof(IServiceA))?.Lifetime, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

You don't need to build the service provider from the service collection.
Note that the code above would fail as well if the `IServiceA` is not registered. That depends on your requirement, you can modify the code as you want. I've just shown the main idea.